# android TextView : Change Text Color on click

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a textfield that behaves like a local link, clicking on it fetches an image from database and shows it. It doesn't ping to server all the time.

Here is the xml code for the text view

```
<TextView android:layout_marginLeft="2dp" android:linksClickable="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Beatles" android:clickable="true" android:id="@+id/Beatles"
            android:textColor="@color/Black"
            android:textSize="12dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColorHighlight="@color/yellow" android:textColorLink="@color/yellow"  android:autoLink="all"></TextView>
```

The question is i want to see the color of text view should be changed in yellow, instead of the same black color,

Just Like the button behavior but instead of changing the background color i want to change a text color

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5371719/change-clickable-textviews-color-on-focus-and-click

Answer (score 25):

I like what Cristian suggests, but extending TextView seems like overkill. In addition, his solution doesn't handle the `MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL` event, making it likely that your text will stay selected even after the clicking is done.

To achieve this effect, I implemented my own onTouchListener in a separate file:

```
public class CustomTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {     
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    switch(motionEvent.getAction()){            
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            ((TextView)view).setTextColor(0xFFFFFFFF); //white
                break;          
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:             
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            ((TextView)view).setTextColor(0xFF000000); //black
                break;
    } 
        return false;   
    } 
}
```

Then you can assign this to whatever TextView you wish:

`newTextView.setOnTouchListener(new CustomTouchListener());`

Comment: Thanks your code works for me. i have done return true in your answer and works for me..

Answer (score 3):

You can create your own TextView class that extends the Android [`TextView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) class and override the [`onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29)

You can then modify the instances text color based on the MotionEvent passed.

For example:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
       // Change color
    } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
       // Change it back
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```