# Whats the Android Style attribute for selected link background color?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a TextView which I dynamically add clickable links via Linkify (with a custom TransformFilter). This all works great. What I would like to do now is change the background color of the link when its clicked. In CSS it would be done via the `:active` pseudo-selector.

I would think I can specify this in styles.xml but I dont know what the parameter name is.

Comment: small world, i saw you on DB once :) are you guys finally making the db android app ?

Comment: Reno - I am putting the finishing touches on it. Slight design / chrome tweaks like this are the final pieces.

Answer (score 7):

Just had this problem myself and the solution for me (but I didn't use Linkify) was the `android:textColorHighlight` attribute. I used `android:linksClickable="true"` instead of `Linkify` though. That won't probably make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

[This might solve your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468380/android-textview-change-text-color-on-click/4468714#4468714) .

Basically you have to define a `ColorStateList` (a xml  to be used as a drawable). For your `TextView`

Comment: Hmm, I think this would only apply to the *whole* TextView and not the actual inner links within a TextView. There can be any number of clickable links within a TextView and when one of those links is clicked I want to alter *its* background. Applying a Selector to the TextView will alter its background as a whole. I would imagine its possible to alter the actual Link selector because I can see that the color does change across devices, which means that device manufacturers are specifying it themselves in their Theme / Style. Thus I just want to override this Theme attribute.

Comment: so which of the states should you look at, for the background of the text that was clicked? and how do you get it?