# Change clickable TextView's color on focus and click?

Tags: android, colors, onclick, textview, hyperlink

I have a clickable TextView that I want to give some colors to. But I don't know how. Here are the relevant code snippets from my two files that I'm working with:

```
TextView title = new TextView(this);
title.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
title.setTextColor(R.color.textcolor);
title.setText(titleLine);
title.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
title.setClickable(true);
title.setId(idLine);
title.setFocusable(true);

title.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

                /* Irrelevant code */                   

    }
});
```

And this is my textcolor.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:color="#000000"/> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_focused="true"
          android:color="#000000"/> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:color="#000000"/> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

When I use the textcolor-file by typing *title.setTextColor(R.color.textcolor);*, the textcolor just becomes grey, regardless if I press it or so. Which is strange since I have written "#000000" in all color fields.
But if I remove the setTextColor code, gets the textView a light grey color, and when I press it, it becomes black. But that aren't the colors that I want.

So, can anyone help me with this problem?

Just to clarify: I want to be able to specify the colors for the text when it's normal, pressed and focused.

Comment: For people referring this page via search, do refer my answer if you are looking to use colors and not `ColorStateList`. My solution works without writing any code in Java :)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

If you want to set stateful color from code, you need to pass in [`ColorStateList`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/ColorStateList) as an argument to [`setTextColor`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextColor(android.content.res.ColorStateList)) passing an int to the method results in setting the color to all the states. It also looks like your xml is not totally correct. Example from `ColorStateList` docs looks like(should be located like this: `res/color/selector_txt.xml`):

```
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="@color/testcolor1"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:state_enabled="false" android:color="@color/testcolor2" />
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="@color/testcolor3" />
    <item android:color="@color/testcolor5"/>
 </selector>
```

UPD on how to set a `ColorStateList` to text color:

```
ColorStateList cl = null;
try {
   XmlResourceParser xpp = getResources().getXml(R.color.selector_txt);
   cl = ColorStateList.createFromXml(getResources(), xpp);
} catch (Exception e) {}
```

***Note***: The method `createFromXml(Resources, XmlPullParser parser)` was deprecated in API level 23.
Use `createFromXml(Resources, XmlPullParser parser, Theme)`

With XML its as easy as:

```
android:textColor="@color/selector_txt"
```

Comment: I changed my XML file to what you suggested, and I did some searching on how I was supposed to send a ColorStateList in the setTextColor method. And I found this useful post: http://www.anddev.org/post27828.html#p27828 So now it's all working correctly. :) However, I need to tweak the states a bit in the xml document.

Comment: @Daniel Jonsson I've added the code from the post to the answer, so it would be easier for someone else.

Comment: to set it programatically use this: myTextView.setTextColor(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.selector_txt));

Answer (score 50):

Step 1: Set the text color in xml like this

> android:textColor="@color/text_color"

Step2: Create **res/color/text_color.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item android:state_pressed="true"
      android:color="#ffffffff"/> <!-- pressed -->
<item android:state_focused="true"
      android:color="#ff0000ff"/> <!-- focused -->
<item android:color="#ff000000"/>  <!--default -->

</selector>
```

Comment: @AlwaysConfused, why? What is a device, OS version?

Answer (score 17):

Try this one.. It worked for me:

**File name: res/color/bg_tab_text_color.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="false" android:color="@color/tab_unselected_text_color"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/tab_selected_text_color"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="true" android:color="@color/tab_selected_text_color"/>
    <item android:color="@color/tab_unselected_text_color"></item>
</selector>
```

Try setting the color in xml layout as:

```
android:textColor="@color/bg_tab_text_color"
```

Comment: perfect save my time dude :)

Answer (score 10):

Look in R.java class (it's generated automatically). You have something like that:

```
 public static final class color {
        public static final int gray_transparent=0x7f050001;
}
```

So in your code in line:

```
title.setTextColor(R.color.textcolor);
```

you're not setting values from textcolor.xml but int from R.java (which contains textcolor.xml address). The valid way to set color is:

```
title.setTextColor(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.textcolor));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! Now it actually reads the colors from the file. :)

However, I'm still having a problem. It just reads the default color. The color won't change if I click on the text, which is strange.Do you know what causes this?

Comment: It should be `getResources().getColorStateList`, not `getResources().getColor`.

Comment: @Patrick yeah, getResources().getColorStateList is really worked.

Comment: Note that this method has been deprecated as of API 23: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getColorStateList(int)

Comment: `ContextCompat.getColorStateList(this,R.color.textcolor)` can be used to get rid of deprecation.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a very simple way programmatically:

```
private void setColorStateList(TextView view) {
        int[][] states = new int[][] {
                new int[] { android.R.attr.state_pressed}, // pressed
                new int[] { android.R.attr.state_focused}, // focused
                new int[] { android.R.attr.state_enabled}  // enabled
        };

        int[] colors = new int[] {
                getResources().getColor(R.color.blue),
                getResources().getColor(R.color.green),
                getResources().getColor(R.color.green) 
        };

        ColorStateList list = new ColorStateList(states, colors);
        view.setTextColor(list);
        view.setClickable(true);
        view.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    }
```

Comment: Excellent, That's the way

Comment: the best answer for those who need a programmatical solution! Works like a charm!

Answer (score 3):

It's very easy.Try this one.. It worked for me:

File name: res/color/bg_tab_text_color.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/blue" />
```

Try setting the color in xml layout as:

```
android:textColor="@color/bg_tab_text_color"
```

Answer (score 1):

**In res/drawable/tab_textColor.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    <item android:color="#CCCCCC" />
</selector>



<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:text="@string/tab_indicator_home"
    android:textColor="@drawable/tab_textcolor"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    tools:ignore="SmallSp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In res/color/text_selector.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/white"
          android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:color="#8020e0"/>
</selector>
```

In layout:

```
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Word"
    android:textColor="@color/text_selector"
    android:textSize="12sp"/>
```

In code:

```
textView.setSelected(false); // To deselect.
textView.setSelected(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

For me just this way worked:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/colorSelected" />
    <item android:state_pressed="false" android:color="@color/colorDefault" />
</selector>
```