# How to set text color as link?

Tags: android, textview

I have textview which I want to change the color when I focus or cliclked it like a link text in web I have try to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5371719/change-clickable-textviews-color-on-focus-and-click) but it still doesn't work

please help, thanks

this is my java code

```
public class TextColorActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
 ColorStateList cl = null;
private TextView title;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    title = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.hello); 
    try {
        Log.d("test","try");        
       XmlResourceParser xpp = getResources().getXml(R.drawable.selector_txt);
       cl = ColorStateList.createFromXml(getResources(), xpp);
    } catch (Exception e) {}
    title.setTextColor(cl);
    title.setFocusable(true);
    title.setClickable(true);
    title.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

                  Log.d("test","click");               

        }
    });
}
```

this is my selector_txt.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_focused="true" android:color="@color/Darkgoldenrod"/>
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:state_enabled="false"  
android:color="@color/Darkgreen" />
<item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="@color/Red" />
<item android:color="@color/blue"/>
```

and this is my main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/hello" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello" 
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:duplicateParentState="true"/>
```

Comment: what's the problem you are facing?

Comment: It change to testcolor5 but it can't change to another color neither I focus nor clicked

Comment: <item android:state_pressed="true" android:state_enabled="false"  
android:color="@color/Darkgreen" /> change this line with <item android:state_pressed="true" android:state_enabled="true"  
android:color="@color/Darkgreen" />, and update me if its working or not

Answer (score 0):

You can also set your color in the xml if you want. Just create a color folder in your res folder and move the xml file there then you can set it via `android:textColor="@color/selector_txt"`

Regards the problem you're having. Android will always use the first match in a selector. If a TextView is pressed it is also focused. So add `android:pressed="false"` to your first item or move the line after the pressed status line.

That's the full xml:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
> <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
> <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="@color/Red" /> 
> <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/Darkgreen" /> 
> <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="@color/Darkgoldenrod"/>
> <item android:color="@color/blue"/>
> </selector>
> ```

Comment: I've just seen that you also look for enabled=false in your pressed state. Remove this and move the third item first then it should work.
I'll update my answer with the whole xml

Comment: The selector should definitely work. There must be a problem somewhere else. You're sure the onClick event is being fired? Can you see the log?

Comment: Did you move the selector to the color folder? You can then access it via R.color.selector_txt
Otherwise I'm out of ideas

Comment: Yes, I move it already but it still doesn't work , anyway thank you very much and if you can find other ideas please help me :)

Comment: `} catch (Exception e) {}` Never make empty catch blocks. Are you sure you don't get any exception there?