# How to change color of the text in TextView on hover like in css?

Tags: android

How to change color of the text in TextView on hover like in css with selector? I know for button to define selector with items

```
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/down"
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:state_enabled="true">
</item>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/up"
    android:state_focused="true"
    android:state_enabled="true">
</item>
```

but I need for TextView textColor, but item doesn't recognize that attribute. Is there way to do this from xml and not from code 
?

Comment: This may help you  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5371719/change-clickable-textviews-color-on-focus-and-click

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Add that selector as a resource file (`res/color/text_color.xml`)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="@color/focused_text_color"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:state_enabled="false" android:color="@color/pressed_text_color" />
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="@color/disabled_text_color" />
    <item android:color="@color/default_text_color"/>
</selector>
```

And use it:

```
android:textColor="@color/text_color"
```