# How to change the TextView Color on click of a layout in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to change the background image and TextView Color on click of a layout .The background color is chnaging properly but my textview color is not changing.Here is my XML code :

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/flight_relative"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imgLogo"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_effect"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/flight_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/flight_list_image"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/flight_list_image"
            android:text="@string/flight_tittle"
            android:textColor="#152b72"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/content_flight"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/flight_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/flight_list_image"
            android:text="@string/flight_content"
            android:textColor="#2f2f2f"
            android:textSize="10sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/flight_arrow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/flight_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/flight_list_image"
            android:layout_width="50dip"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:padding="3dip"
            android:src="@drawable/flight_icon" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Code to chnage the textview color is :

```
flightRelative = (RelativeLayout )findViewById(R.id.flight_relative);
        flightRelative.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                flight = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.flight_content);
                flight.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

            }
        });
```

What wrong i am doing please suggest me .For the first time it is not working on second time it is working

Comment: Does the code in onClick executes? Fot what layout did you add onCLickListener to change background color?

Comment: @cooperok for flight_relative i have added onCLickListener rest on the things are working properly but the textview color is not chnaging properly.

Comment: after the onclick i have to reset the textview color to the default color

Comment: What do you mean by "the textview color is not chnaging properly"? You r code is right, i have only one variant, is that you added listener to flight_relative twice

Comment: I got my solution from this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5371719/change-clickable-textviews-color-on-focus-and-click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You should add this definitely working.I am also check it out...

```
flightRelative.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
       TextView flight = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.flight_content);
       flight.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));

    }
});
```

Comment: is there any way to reset the text color after the on click

Comment: i am not understand what u r telling

Comment: i want some thing like in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8180045/how-to-change-color-of-the-text-in-textview-on-hover-like-in-css

Answer (score 0):

you should use

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            flight = (TextView)flightRelative.findViewById(R.id.flight_content);
            flight.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

        }
```

I believe it should work now.

Comment: flight.setTextColor("#fff");

Comment: @JesusS it is showing the error i.e The method setTextColor(int) in the type TextView is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Comment: You can set color from your resources, `getResources().getColor(R.color.mycolor1)`
  or use rgb values `flight.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255, 255, 255));`

Comment: add your color to resources , colors.xml 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <color name="yourColor">#COLOR</color>
</resources>

Comment: you're right, sorry. The correct one is

flight.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));

Color must have the 6 character format