# How to make child views get "onpress" event from root view?

Tags: android

I'm used to the fact that items of listview without any problem (even with complicated layout) handle onpress events (some actions that makes it pressed and unpressed). But now I want the same from LinearLayout - if you press anyway on layout, all descendants should get onpress events.

This is the part of my fragment layout, which should be highlighted onpress event.

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_about_fragment_feedback"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_height="54dp"
            android:background="@drawable/about_item_bkg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <ImageView
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/about_item_feedback_icon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"/>

        <TextView
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/about_fragment_feedback"
                android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:textColor="@drawable/about_item_textcolor"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Background of root layout changes onpress, but textcolor of descendants don't. Looks like they don't get event from root.

So, can you help?

UPDATE: LinearLayout ll_about_fragment_feedback has bound OnClickListener and there is everything fine with selecrors

Comment: Why not set an `onClickListener` to the container, the `LinearLayout` in your case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a `Selector` to apply to all views under your `LinearLayout` then you just need to add `android:duplicateParentState="true"` to all of the child views.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_about_fragment_feedback"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="54dp"
    android:background="@drawable/about_item_bkg"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
        android:background="@drawable/about_item_feedback_icon"
        android:duplicateParentState="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:text="@string/about_fragment_feedback"
        android:textColor="@drawable/about_item_textcolor"
        android:textSize="16dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just bind your `onClickListener` to root object of your layout (`ll_about_fragment_feedback`) and that's it.

Comment: I know that there is no onpress event. I mean something that makes it pressed. Not click

Comment: @bluebyte do you mean your looking for a `Selector`? Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5374283/1134705)

Comment: If you are asking about visual feedback of clicking then listener got absolutely nothing in common with it. As Asok stated, you need to use correct Selector.

Comment: @WebnetMobile.com In this case only root layout gets pressed state, descendents - no

Comment: @WebnetMobile.com there is everything fine with selectors

Comment: if childs' background is transparent that shall suffice anyway

Comment: android:textColor="@drawable/about_item_textcolor" this is font color selector. It should become pressed when I touch root layout (which is bound to onclicklistener) in any place. My English is not so good - its difficult to describe what I want:)

Comment: @bluebyte If the `Selector` is set up then add `android:duplicateParentState="true"` to all of the child views within your `LinearLayout`. I *think* that will do the trick.

Comment: @Asok Thank you so much! Add this as your answer - I check it as right