# TextView text color changes on changing the background color

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-drawable, xml-drawable

I am using `TextView` as a `Button` (flat UI) in my android application. Below is the code

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_background"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
            android:paddingTop="16dp"
            android:text="Sign Up"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
```

The background drawable 'button_background' is

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="#FCD5A5" android:state_enabled="false" />
<item android:drawable="#F7941E" />
```

So when `Button` is **enabled** it should have **dark orange background** otherwise light orange background.

Background color is working fine with both the states (enabled and disabled) **but text color is also getting changed**. It remains white in enabled state but changes to dark grey in disabled state. I want to keep it white in both the states.

Comment: [try this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5371719/change-clickable-textviews-color-on-focus-and-click) this willo deffinately help you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently looking at how to do this for your selector. But for now, you could always do this and call it once to initialize and then when the state changes:

```
private void updateTextColor(TextView view, Context context) {
    if (!view.isEnabled()) {
        view.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

textcolorselector.xml <= put this file in drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:color="@color/general_blue" android:state_enabled="true"></item>
<item android:color="@color/general_gray" android:state_enabled="false"></item>
<item android:color="@color/general_blue"></item>
```

add this line to color.xml file

```
 <drawable name="textviewcolor">@drawable/textcolorselector</drawable>
```

and finally apply this to your layout

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_background"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:text="Sign Up"
        android:textColor="@color/textviewcolor" // <== i made change here!
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Comment: This is showing me error "textviewcolor" is not available in colors.xml. Are you sure it is compilable ?

Comment: yes working fine for me, update your code color.xml, textcolorselector.xml and layout