# Load image with string from 'class model'

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a problem with loading images with my 'class model' my list(name) on class model works fine!. but the images is not loading from my class model.

[![Class model][1]][1] **Look at on 'red square' why `setImages` is not on use?**

[![Populating the list][2]][2] Populating the list!, like i said! the ""name is working. but the image is all the same [![I don't know why.][3]][3]

Layout of my `@Override
    public RecyclerViewAdapter2.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_marca_tag_servico_layout, parent, false);
        return new RecyclerViewAdapter2.ViewHolder(view);
    }`

[![I dont have ideia why the image is not loading][4]][4]

```
    di_tags1();
    DICategoriasRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.DICategoriasRecyclerView);
    selectedItemCount = 0;

    recyclerViewAdapter2 = new RecyclerViewAdapter2(taglista, this);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    DICategoriasRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    DICategoriasRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this,2));
    DICategoriasRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerViewAdapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();

    DIBotaoContinuarTag = (Button) findViewById(R.id.DIBotaoContinuarTag);

    DIBotaoContinuarTag.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openDIContinuarTag();
        }
    });

    DICategoriasRecyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter2);
}



    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DISubCategorias.class);
    intent.putStringArrayListExtra("Result", ListaFinal);
    startActivity(intent);

    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // FUCK
    //===========================

}

// quando o usuário clicar no item na lista RecyclerView, nosso adaptador criado invocará a seguinte função e passará a posição.
@Override
public void selectedItemCount(int count) {
    selectedItemCount = count;
}


@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
}

}
```

**I just want to know how can i load the image from this class model? because the string works fine.**

**EDIT, MY ADAPTER**

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter2 extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter2.ViewHolder> {

ArrayList<TagsModel> TagsDaMarca;//change like this
ArrayList<TagsModel> SubServicoTagsDaMarca;//change like this
ArrayList<TagsModel> DICategorias;//change like this
ArrayList<String> DISubCategorias;

HashMap<Integer, List<String>> ListaCatSubCat = new HashMap<Integer, List<String>>();
public static SparseBooleanArray sparseBooleanArray;
// for identifying: in list which items are selected
OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener listener;
int meutotal = 0;


public RecyclerViewAdapter2(ArrayList<TagsModel> TagsDaMarca1, OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener listener) {
    TagsDaMarca = TagsDaMarca1;
    SubServicoTagsDaMarca = TagsDaMarca1;
    DICategorias = TagsDaMarca1;


    sparseBooleanArray = new SparseBooleanArray();
    this.listener = listener;
}


@Override
public RecyclerViewAdapter2.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_marca_tag_servico_layout, parent, false);
    return new RecyclerViewAdapter2.ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewAdapter2.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    TagsModel item = DICategorias.get(position); //change like this

    if (item.equals("0")) {
        holder.itemTextView.setText(item.getName());
        holder.DICategoriasIcones.setImageResource(item.getImages());
        holder.itemTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        holder.itemTextView.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255, 0, 167));
        holder.DICategoriasIcones.setEnabled(false);
        holder.itemTextView.setEnabled(false);
    } else if (item.equals("1")) {
        holder.itemTextView.setText(item.getName());
        holder.DICategoriasIcones.setImageResource(item.getImages());
        holder.itemTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        holder.itemTextView.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255, 0, 167));
        holder.DICategoriasIcones.setEnabled(false);
        holder.itemTextView.setEnabled(false);
    } else if (item.equals("2")) {
        holder.itemTextView.setText(item.getName());
        holder.DICategoriasIcones.setImageResource(item.getImages());
        holder.itemTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        holder.itemTextView.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255, 0, 167));
        holder.DICategoriasIcones.setEnabled(false);
        holder.itemTextView.setEnabled(false);
    } else if (item.equals("3")) {
        holder.itemTextView.setText(item.getName());
        holder.itemTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        holder.DICategoriasIcones.setImageResource(item.getImages());
        holder.itemTextView.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255, 0, 167));
        holder.DICategoriasIcones.setEnabled(false);
        holder.itemTextView.setEnabled(false);
    } else if (item.equals("4")) {
        holder.itemTextView.setText(item.getName());
        holder.itemTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        holder.DICategoriasIcones.setImageResource(item.getImages());
        holder.itemTextView.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255, 0, 167));
        holder.DICategoriasIcones.setEnabled(false);
        holder.itemTextView.setEnabled(false);
    } else if (item.equals("5")) {
        holder.itemTextView.setText(item.getName());
        holder.itemTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        holder.DICategoriasIcones.setImageResource(item.getImages());
        holder.itemTextView.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255, 0, 167));
        holder.DICategoriasIcones.setEnabled(false);
        holder.itemTextView.setEnabled(false);
    } else if (item.equals("6")) {
        holder.itemTextView.setText(item.getName());
        holder.itemTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        holder.DICategoriasIcones.setImageResource(item.getImages());
        holder.itemTextView.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255, 0, 167));
        holder.DICategoriasIcones.setEnabled(false);
        holder.itemTextView.setEnabled(false);
    } else if (item.equals("7")) {
        holder.itemTextView.setText(item.getName());
        holder.itemTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        holder.DICategoriasIcones.setImageResource(item.getImages());
        holder.itemTextView.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255, 0, 167));
        holder.DICategoriasIcones.setEnabled(false);
        holder.itemTextView.setEnabled(false);
    } else if (item.equals("8")) {
        holder.itemTextView.setText(item.getName());
        holder.itemTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        holder.DICategoriasIcones.setImageResource(item.getImages());
        holder.itemTextView.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255, 0, 167));
        holder.DICategoriasIcones.setEnabled(false);
        holder.itemTextView.setEnabled(false);
    } else if (item.equals("9")) {
        holder.itemTextView.setText(item.getName());
        holder.itemTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        holder.DICategoriasIcones.setImageResource(item.getImages());
        holder.itemTextView.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255, 0, 167));
        holder.DICategoriasIcones.setEnabled(false);
        holder.itemTextView.setEnabled(false);
    } else if (item.equals("10")) {
        holder.itemTextView.setText(item.getName());
        holder.itemTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        holder.DICategoriasIcones.setImageResource(item.getImages());
        holder.itemTextView.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255, 0, 167));
        holder.DICategoriasIcones.setEnabled(false);
        holder.itemTextView.setEnabled(false);
    } else if (item.equals("11")) {
        holder.itemTextView.setText(item.getName());
        holder.itemTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        holder.DICategoriasIcones.setImageResource(item.getImages());
        holder.itemTextView.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255, 0, 167));
        holder.DICategoriasIcones.setEnabled(false);
        holder.itemTextView.setEnabled(false);
    } else if (item.equals("12")) {
        holder.itemTextView.setText(item.getName());
        holder.itemTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        holder.DICategoriasIcones.setImageResource(item.getImages());
        holder.itemTextView.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255, 0, 167));
        holder.DICategoriasIcones.setEnabled(false);
        holder.itemTextView.setEnabled(false);
    } else if (item.equals("13")) {
        holder.itemTextView.setText(item.getName());
        holder.itemTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        holder.DICategoriasIcones.setImageResource(item.getImages());
        holder.itemTextView.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255, 0, 167));
        holder.DICategoriasIcones.setEnabled(false);
        holder.itemTextView.setEnabled(false);
    } else if (item.equals("14")) {
        holder.itemTextView.setText(item.getName());
        holder.itemTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        holder.DICategoriasIcones.setImageResource(item.getImages());
        holder.itemTextView.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255, 0, 167));
        holder.DICategoriasIcones.setEnabled(false);
        holder.itemTextView.setEnabled(false);
    } else if (item.equals("15")) {
        holder.itemTextView.setText(item.getName());
        holder.itemTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        holder.DICategoriasIcones.setImageResource(item.getImages());
        holder.itemTextView.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255, 0, 167));
        holder.DICategoriasIcones.setEnabled(false);
        holder.itemTextView.setEnabled(false);
    } else if (item.equals("16")) {
        holder.itemTextView.setText(item.getName());
        holder.itemTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        holder.DICategoriasIcones.setImageResource(item.getImages());
        holder.itemTextView.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255, 0, 167));
        holder.DICategoriasIcones.setEnabled(false);
        holder.itemTextView.setEnabled(false);
    } else if (item.equals("17")) {
        holder.itemTextView.setText(item.getName());
        holder.itemTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        holder.DICategoriasIcones.setImageResource(item.getImages());
        holder.itemTextView.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255, 0, 167));
        holder.DICategoriasIcones.setEnabled(false);
        holder.itemTextView.setEnabled(false);
    } else {
        holder.itemTextView.setText(item.getName());
        if (sparseBooleanArray.get(position)) {
            holder.itemTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            holder.itemTextView.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255, 0, 167));
        } else {
            holder.itemTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            holder.itemTextView.setTextColor(Color.rgb(190, 190, 190));
        }
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (TagsDaMarca != null) {
        return TagsDaMarca.size();
    }else if (SubServicoTagsDaMarca != null) {
        return SubServicoTagsDaMarca.size();
    }else if (DICategorias != null) {
        return DICategorias.size();
    }
    return 0;
}


/******** View Holder Class*/
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    TextView itemTextView;
    ImageView DICategoriasIcones;
    public TextView alert;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemTextView);
        itemTextView.setOnClickListener(this);

        DICategoriasIcones = itemView.findViewById(R.id.DICategoriasIcones);
        DICategoriasIcones.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        if (!sparseBooleanArray.get(getAdapterPosition())) {
            if (meutotal < 3) {
                sparseBooleanArray.put(getAdapterPosition(), true);
                notifyItemChanged(getAdapterPosition());
                meutotal = meutotal + 1;
            }
        } else // if clicked item is already selected
        {
            sparseBooleanArray.put(getAdapterPosition(), false);
            notifyItemChanged(getAdapterPosition());
            meutotal = meutotal - 1;
        }
    }
}


public interface OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener {
    public void selectedItemCount(int count);
 }
}
```

**I remove many item from onBindViewHolder because the Body is limited to 30000 characters, i need those conditions because when the user click on item the image and the text needs to change the color**

[![The first image is from i need to add the image!, it's over 42 itens with image i need the the user click on the item the text and the image change the color, And on the same first image it was to be a horizontal roll... but i changed with 2 SpanCount. and the secound image is the subcategories which i use another adapter! they works fine. but the problem is the first image.][5]][5]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing a TagModel with a String. It will always be false and the 'else statement' will be executed. As you don't change the image in the 'else' (only the name), there is your issue.

Just change your adapter code, for example, to:

```
// ...
if (position <= 17) {
    holder.itemTextView.setText(item.getName());
    holder.itemTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    holder.DICategoriasIcones.setImageResource(item.getImages());
    holder.itemTextView.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255, 0, 167));
    holder.DICategoriasIcones.setEnabled(false);
    holder.itemTextView.setEnabled(false);
} else {
    holder.itemTextView.setText(item.getName());
    if (sparseBooleanArray.get(position)) {
        holder.itemTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        holder.itemTextView.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255, 0, 167));
    } else {
        holder.itemTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        holder.itemTextView.setTextColor(Color.rgb(190, 190, 190));
    }
}
```

Anyways, you could remove your else and use a ColorStateList to have the text color changed when clicked. Check a solution here: [Change clickable TextView's color on focus and click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5371719/change-clickable-textviews-color-on-focus-and-click)

Comment: You're comparing a TagModel with a String using equals. It will never be true.
    if (item.equals("0")) {

This way, the else is always being executed and there you don't change the image.
You should compare the position (if position <= 17) { ... }. This will solve the problem. However, I'm still confused with your ifs.

Comment: I admit, i'm confused with myself haha. i will try your  (if position <= 17). let me check

Comment: btw, look at this video  (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dlhfDn8Da5s) i think you will understand a little bit better.

Comment: I forgot to mention! on this video im using the same adapter for 'subcategories' but i changed for adapter 3.

Comment: Omg your logic worked `if position <= 17` now the image has changed!, but how can i change the color of textview on click?. because, now it's pink. I need it to be like on the video above. i've changed on my adapter the holder.itemTextView.setEnabled for TRUE.

Comment: Just use a ColorStateList (and remove your else - it won't be necessary anymore). See [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5371719/change-clickable-textviews-color-on-focus-and-click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5371719/change-clickable-textviews-color-on-focus-and-click) for details.

Comment: Do not forget to mark my answer as the correct one.

Comment: I will never forget you (nohomo) OMG, I lost 6 days in that SH*T, thank you my friend </3.  I will accept for sure your answer.