# Android: On Textview Tap Change background color of only the text excluding margin/padding

Tags: android, textview

I have a TextView that is aligned with other 2 items occupying the remaining space. The TextView is clickable and background color of textview changes on click. The issue is the background of complete view is changed instead of only the Text in textview. Is there any way to change the background color only for the text?

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/client_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/client_header_end_text"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/client_header_back"
        android:background="@drawable/action_bar_item_background"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"/>
```

action_bar_item_background:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/action_bar_item_background_pressed" />
</selector>
```

action_bar_item_background_pressed:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <solid android:color="@color/light_grey" />
</shape>
```

Comment: you can do it by text.setTextColor();

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your TextView on a FrameLayout, and change the layout_width of the TextView to wrap_content, and center horizontal. You are however going to decrease the "touch area"... To fix that, register your touch listener on the FrameLayout (move the TextView ID?), and tell the TextView to duplicateParentState="true". Something like:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/client_header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/client_header_end_text"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/client_header_back">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/action_bar_item_background"
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="Hellooooo" />
</FrameLayout>
```

If is just the text color that you want to change, see [android TextView : Change Text Color on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468380/android-textview-change-text-color-on-click)

Answer (score -1):

```
onclick() {
        textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.client_header);
        textview.setTextColor(yourColor);
    }
```

You can change the Color inside your activity in this way