# How to change TextView text color on selection?

Tags: android, textview

My scenario is when user click on a `TextView` text, it will change it's color black to red. I have tried to solve this problem but nothing happened. Here is my effort: My `TextView`

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textColor="@color/text_selector"
        android:text="Shamima Sultana Shaumi"/>
```

and the text_selector class is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="@android:color/red"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:state_enabled="false" android:color="@android:color/red" />
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="@android:color/red" />
    <item android:color="@android:color/black"/>
</selector>
```

Whenever I click on `TextView`, nothing is happened. I can't figured out what was my problem.

Comment: you want the color to change for the duration of the click (so as long as it's pressed), or do you want the color of the text to change after the click?

Comment: Set your background to that drawable, not your textColor.

Comment: @BartekLipinski I want to change the text color after the click.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The selector can be e.g. this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="@android:color/red" />
    <item android:color="@android:color/black"/>
</selector>
```

and use this `OnClickListener` for your `textView`:

```
textView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        boolean isSelectedAfterClick = !v.isSelected();
        v.setSelected(isSelectedAfterClick);

        if (isSelectedAfterClick){
            //do something
        } else {
            //do something
        }
    }
});
```

Instead of `state_selected`, `isSelected` and `setSelected` you can use (respectively) `state_activated`, `isActivated` and `setActivated`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried [[android TextView : Change Text Color on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468380/android-textview-change-text-color-on-click)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468380/android-textview-change-text-color-on-click)

Or try using an OnTouchListener or if you want to perform OnClick may be OnClickListener for the Text View in Java Code and turn the Color.

Comment: No but I want the color change through xml selector after textclick.