# I want to change the color text using styles,

Tags: android, textview

This is my `TextView`

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/home_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:text="Home"
    android:textColor="@drawable/color_state"/>
```

This is my `color_state.xml` code in drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:color="#fff"/>
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:state_selected="true"
        android:color="#ff0000"/>
</selector>
```

I have searched similar questions but what I want is a different thing, all the questions which stack suggested "possible duplicate of", I already tried but that is not what I want, that's why I asked this question with all the explanation that I need.Existing question only changes the color when `TexttView` is clicked
I have two TextView in a `LinearLayout`, I just want to change the color of my text when I click on it, with this code I can change color but when I release click the color goes back to the original.All I want is to change the color when I click on TextView and the change should be permanent until another view is not clicked
Please any help will be appreciated

Comment: You will have to do that through code to maintain the state of the text color. Once you have selected any other view, manually reset the others.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change clickable TextView's color on focus and click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5371719/change-clickable-textviews-color-on-focus-and-click)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android TextView : Change Text Color on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468380/android-textview-change-text-color-on-click)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of Enum class to easily define the colors wanted, and this way, you'll be able to increase the amount of supported colors without too much changes in your code.

### Enum class

```
public enum ColorFactory {

    BLACK(R.id.textView1, R.color.black),
    WHITE(R.id.textView2, R.color.white),
    BLUE(R.id.textView2, R.color.blue),
    RED(R.id.textView2, R.color.red),
    CYAN(R.id.textView2, R.color.cyan),
    GREEN(R.id.textView2, R.color.green),
    GREY(R.id.textView2, R.color.grey),
    YELLOW(R.id.textView2, R.color.yellow),
    PINK(R.id.textView2, R.color.pink),
    PURPLE(R.id.textView2, R.color.purple),
    BROWN(R.id.textView2, R.color.brown),
    CUSTOM(R.id.textView2, R.color.custom);

    int id;
    int color;

    ColorFactory(int id, int color) {
        this.id = id;
        this.color = color;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public int getColor() {
        return color;
    }


    public static int getColorById(int id) {
        for (ColorFactory currentEnumElement : values()) {
            if (currentEnumElement.getId() == id) {
                return currentEnumElement.getColor();
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

And you'll have to have those colors defined in your `colors.xml` file as following

### Colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
    <color name="black">#000000</color>
    <color name="white">#ffffff</color>
    <color name="blue">#0000ff</color>
    <color name="red">#ff0000</color>
    <color name="cyan">#00f2ff</color>
    <color name="green">#00ff00</color>
    <color name="grey">#8b8378</color>
    <color name="yellow">#ffd700</color>
    <color name="pink">#e8a4a3</color>
    <color name="purple">#b72bef</color>
    <color name="brown">#a7823e</color>
    <color name="custom">#990000</color>
</resources>
```

And to the final, the code to use it...(simplified)

### Code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    TextView textView1;
    TextView textView2;
    .
    .
    .

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        textView2 = . . . .
        .
        .
        .
        .

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.textView1:
                textView1.setTextColor(ColorFactory.getColorById(view.getId()));
                break;
            case R.id.textView2:
                .
                .
                .
        }
    }
}
```

It should allow you to set the colors as a result of a click.
NOTE: you can also use [ButterKnife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) to bind the views to improve the readability of your code and so on..
Hope it helps.

Comment: this answer taught me something new :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the textview color change permanently when clicked and back to normal when another textview clicked. You need to set on java code like this.

```
TextView home = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.home_text);
TextView another = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.another_text);
home.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            home.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            another.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        }
    });
another.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            home.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            another.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        }
    });
```

Comment: What if I have 16 View? The code length will increase

Comment: You can make OnClickListener class so you dont need to write your code again and set it on your button

Comment: @Pokemon - Take a look to my answer, it resolves the multiple (16 for example) textviews to handle